# How to read GPS Coordinates from JPG EXIF using CCR.EXIF in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, gps

It's quite easy setting the GPS coordinates using the GPSLatitude and GPSLatitude properties Assign method, but reading the coords has me stumped. I've trying to access the TGPSLongitude class, but none of the properties or methods would render me a real / float or even DMS of the coordinates.

Sample image: http://www.cde.co.za/share/IMG_5889.JPG

My current code that's not compiling:

```
imgJpg: TJpegImageEx;
GPS_D: Real;

try
  imgJpg.LoadFromFile(FolderName+'\'+SR.Name);
  GPS_D:= imgJpg.ExifData.GPSLatitude.Degrees;
except
  GPS_D:= 0;
end;
```

The compiler stops at where I try to assign GPS_D with the error "[DCC Error] Main.pas(205): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Real' and 'TTiffLongWordFraction'" This is obviously because I can't assign the Degrees property to a real. The question is how do I extract the degrees or decimal value from TGPSLongitude ?

Comment: *My current code that's not compiling* What compiler error, on which line? Also, what is `TdmSH` and its method `DMStoDec`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg DMStoDec takes 3 real values and converts it to GPS Decimal. However I've simplified the source sample. The compiler stops at where I try to assign GPS_D with the error "[DCC Error] Main.pas(205): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Real' and 'TTiffLongWordFraction'" This is obviously because I can't assign the Degrees property to a real. The question is how do I extract the degrees or decimal value from TGPSLongitude ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to extract GPS information as a `string`:

```
var myLat, myLong : string;
...
myLat := myJpeg.ExifData.GPSLatitude.AsString ; 
myLong := myJpeg.ExifData.GPSLongitude.AsString ;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation existing inside the CCRExif 1.5.1 -

> GPS
>
> The Exif standard allows setting GPS (i.e., positioning) data,
>   which is stored in its own section/sub-IFD. Using TExifData, you can
>   both read and write this, the standard set of GPS tags being exposed
>   as properties on that class. An important thing to note, however, is
>   that GPS coordinates can be expressed in two different ways, as either
>   a single decimal value or in terms of degrees, minutes and seconds.
>   Exif uses the second form, so if you wish to assign GPS coordinates to
>   an image, and all you have are the required values expressed as
>   decimals, you’ll need to convert to the other form first. (For ‘one
>   off’ conversions, you can use the following website:
>   http://www.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html.) Once you
>   have coordinates in the required form however, assigning them to an
>   image goes as thus:

```
with TExifData.Create do 
try
  LoadFromGraphic(ImageFile); 
  GPSLatitude.Assign(51, 25, 32.1, ltNorth);
  GPSLongitude.Assign(0, 12, 29.2, lnEast); 
  SaveToGraphic(ImageFile);
finally 
 Free; 
end;
```

Looking inside of the source code lean to:

```
TGPSLatitude = class(TGPSCoordinate)
```

and the declaration of the **TGPSCoordinate** class has in the public section

```
property Degrees: TExifFraction index 0 read GetValue;
property Minutes: TExifFraction index 1 read GetValue;
property Seconds: TExifFraction index 2 read GetValue;
property Direction: AnsiChar read GetDirectionChar write SetDirectionChar;
```

Also, there are several demo applications inside the zip file.

LE: After reading the comments, I took a look again at the demos, and in the **ExifList** demo you have in **ExifListFrame.pas** the following code:

```
 procedure AddValue(const Name: string; Coord: TGPSCoordinate); overload;
  var
    DirectionStr: string;
  {$IFDEF BUGGYCOMPILER}
    Degrees, Minutes, Seconds: TExifFraction; //work around D2006 compiler bug with intermediate vars
  {$ENDIF}
  begin
    if Coord.MissingOrInvalid then Exit;
    case Coord.Direction of
      'N': DirectionStr := 'north';
      'S': DirectionStr := 'south';
      'W': DirectionStr := 'west';
      'E': DirectionStr := 'east';
    else DirectionStr := '';
    end;
  {$IFDEF BUGGYCOMPILER}
    Degrees := Coord.Degrees;
    Minutes := Coord.Minutes;
    Seconds := Coord.Seconds;
    AddValue(Name, '%g°, %g minutes and %g seconds %s', [Degrees.Quotient,
      Minutes.Quotient, Seconds.Quotient, DirectionStr]);
  {$ELSE}
    AddValue(Name, '%g°, %g minutes and %g seconds %s', [Coord.Degrees.Quotient,
      Coord.Minutes.Quotient, Coord.Seconds.Quotient, DirectionStr]);
  {$ENDIF}
  end;
```

Comment: I don't have a Delphi installation at hand, so I can not provide you a full example of the usage of the class.

Comment: thanks, I have read the documentation thoroughly and your extract shows how to ASSIGN the TGPSCoordinate instance, i.e. write it. I have an existing JPG that's geo tagged and I need the coordinates off it. The Degrees, minutes, seconds properties are of TExifFraction type, a packed record with components that's not clear how to get the actual value. See my attempts in source code added above.

Answer (score 2):

Looking in depth at the source, it seems one can use the "Quotient" property. In stead of storing the decimal float, the developer chose to store the components Numerator, Denominator and Quotient.

I don't think it's how it's meant to be used, but it's working! Thanks for everyone's time.

So, to read the GPS Coordinates from a JPG file using CCR.EXIF, I do the following:

```
var
    imgJpg: TJpegImageEx;
    d,m,s,lat: real;

imgJpg.LoadFromFile(FolderName+'\'+SR.Name); {Load the particular JPG File }
d:= imgJpg.ExifData.GPSLatitude.Degrees.Quotient; {Degrees}
m:= imgJpg.ExifData.GPSLatitude.Minutes.Quotient; {Minutes}
s:= imgJpg.ExifData.GPSLatitude.Seconds.Quotient; {Seconds}

{Now determine the sign}
if imgJpg.ExifData.GPSLatitude.Direction=ltNorth then
  ref:= 1
else
  ref:= -1;

{Convert to decimal}
lat:= ref*(d+(m/60)+(s/60/60));
```

lat now contains the latitude. Same can be done for long of course.

Comment: Can someone tell me how I can to the exact thing in Lazarus?

Comment: Hein, you've helped me greatly with your solution. I would like to add that CCRExif doesn't work reliably in a number of instances. In a JPG from my Xiaomi Mi 8 it gave false (void) values for GPSLatitudeRef, GPSLatitude.Direction, GPSLatitude.MissingOrInvalid and so forth. Here you can resort to GPSLatitude.ToString which contains the direction ('N' or 'S') in the last character. Also it will be '0,0,0,N' when no GPS tag is present, which apparently is more reliable than MissingOrInvalid.

Comment: Correction: In fact it will be '0,0,0N' when no GPS tag is present.